# Efficiently convert Foreign.Ptr Word8 (or ByteString) to UArray Int Word8

Tags: parsing, haskell, packet, pcap

I'm doing some Network capture with `Network.Pcap` ([pcap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pcap-0.4.5.2/docs/Network-Pcap.html)) and plan to do some inspection using `Net.PacketParsing` ([network-house](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-house-0.1.0.2/docs/Net-PacketParsing.html)). To do so, it looks like i have to put my packet parsing in either

```
Pcap.Callback :: PktHdr -> Ptr Word8 -> IO ()
```

or

```
Pcap.CallbackBS :: PktHdr -> ByteString -> IO ().
```

And work on the packet as either a 'Ptr Word8' or 'ByteString'. On the packet parsing side, I have:

```
Net.Packet.toInPack :: UArray Int Word8 -> InPacket
```

to get to the `InPacket` type that's needed for the parsing. So, what's left for me is to convert the 'Ptr' or 'ByteString' to 'UArray'--either purely or in IO. I suppose I can unpack the `ByteString` to `[Word8]`, and from there to the `UArray`, but there seems like there must be a better way.

I'm also concerned about my choice of libraries. I've used network-house in the past and found it quite nice, but it is getting old and uses UArray, which itself seems a little archaic. So suggestions for a better starting point are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ByteString` and `Ptr Word8` point to external heap, while `UArray` is on GHC heap, so any conversion function must copy over the data.

I have not found any direct conversion function in libraries, but fortunately there's a GHC primitive which does exactly what we want, called [`copyAddrToByteArray#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.2.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#v:copyAddrToByteArray-35-). This lets us convert with the bare minimum overhead:

```
{-# language MagicHash, UnboxedTuples #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Internal as B
import qualified Data.Array.Base as A

import GHC.Types
import GHC.Prim
import GHC.Magic (runRW#)
import GHC.ForeignPtr
import Data.Word

-- when using GHC 8.2.x or later:
byteStringToUArray :: B.ByteString -> A.UArray Int Word8
byteStringToUArray (B.PS (ForeignPtr addr _) (I# start) (I# len)) =
  runRW# $ \s -> case newByteArray# len s of
    (# s, marr #) -> case copyAddrToByteArray# (plusAddr# addr start) marr 0# len s of
      s -> case unsafeFreezeByteArray# marr s of
        (# _, arr #) -> A.UArray 0 (I# (len -# 1#)) (I# len) arr
{-# inline byteStringToUArray #-}

-- when using GHC 8.0.x:
byteStringToUArray :: B.ByteString -> A.UArray Int Word8
byteStringToUArray (B.PS (ForeignPtr addr _) (I# start) (I# len)) =
  case (runRW# $ \s -> case newByteArray# len s of
    (# s, marr #) -> case copyAddrToByteArray# (plusAddr# addr start) marr 0# len s of
      s -> case unsafeFreezeByteArray# marr s of
        (# s, arr #) -> (# s, A.UArray 0 (I# (len -# 1#)) (I# len) arr #)) of
    (# _, res #) -> res
{-# inline byteStringToUArray #-}
```

But in general, you're right that `array` is outdated and rarely used now.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good but I'm unable to compile. What version of ghc-prim are you using? It will be difficult for me to go past 0.5.0.0?

Comment: Sorry, I added a version for ghc-8.0.x (prim-0.5.0.0) as well. The difference is the type of `runRW#`.